# Asp.net, broadcast simple message

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, udp, broadcast

I need to broadcast simple messages like this:
"Client-a: login to webservice and read your instructions"
"Client-f: login to webservice and read your instructions"
...

Clients may wait for their instructions anything from a few milliseconds to a few days.

Once every few minutes clients will login and search for their instructions regardless of any broadcast message. so, there is nothing mission critical with this task. If for any reason client misses a message, it will read it later.

All clients can be connected to the same socket. Nothing secret is broadcasted; Only some Guid codes one after the other. Clients will read secret things by logging into server.

My questions:
1- I think UDP is the correct protocol for this task.
2- server needs to be hosted on a shared plan. Where shall I instantiate the socket stuff on the server?as far as I can remember, asp.net application doesn't keep anything in memory for more than 2 minutes.

There are plenty of samples for socket programing in winforms applications on the net. But very rare or nothing on web server.

Comment: Could SignalR help you in anyway?

Comment: Im studying it right now. Seems it is the official answer. But has tons of extra capabilities which one needs to master it for a simple job. First thing that grabed my attention is use of owin file for permanent  instanciating the stuff.